# Storing a Cv::Mat's data in a std::vector

Tags: opencv, stdvector

I want to copy the data from a cv::Mat to an std::vector. I could obviously go through the entire Mat and copy each value one by one, but I was hoping that there might be an easier way using copyTo, clone, or some sort of pointer manipulation.

Does anyone have any insight on this problem?

Thanks

Comment: In OpenCV is an automatic converter from std::vector<> to cv::Mat. It may be that there is the opposite converter, too. Check the InputArray/OuptupArray properties. You may convert a mat to InputArray, and then use getVector() or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Mat is CV_8UC1, you can do following.

```
cv::Mat mat(nrows,ncols,CV_8UC1);
...
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
vec.assign(mat.data,mat.data+nrows*ncols);
```

For multiple channel image with different pixel type, I think you will be able to easily generalize the code above.

Comment: You could also use vector constructor with range arguments `std::vector<unsigned char> vec(mat.data, mat.data+nrows*ncols)` directly

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for myself. I had `Mat matVec2f` of size Nx1, type Vec2f, and a vector of size N. The following code copies the Mat's data to the vector. I believe this should work equally well for data types other than Vec2f.

```
int N = 10;
vector<Point2f> vec(N);
matVec2f.copyTo(Mat(vec, false));
```